# Python Convert unusual date string to datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

I have date string like this:

```
Saturday, 30 Nov, 2013
```

So it is like `Day_Name, Day, Month_Name_3_Letters, Year`.

I wonder what is the best way to convert it to datetime format using python?

I using like this:

```
datetime.strptime((row[7].split(',')[1] + row[7].split(',')[2]).replace(' ',''), "%d%b%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Take a look at the built in [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
 import datetime as dt
 s = 'Saturday, 30 Nov, 2013'
 d = dt.datetime.strptime(s,'%A, %d %b, %Y')
```

Result:

```
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 30, 0, 0)
```

As you'll see from the reference:

```
%A    Weekday as locale’s full name.
%d    Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%b    Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
%Y    Year with century as a decimal number.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `strptime` function and initialize it as the following:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime_object = datetime.strptime('Saturday, 30 Nov, 2013', '%A, %d %b, %Y')

print datetime_object
```

> Conversely, the datetime.strptime() class method creates a datetime
>   object from a string representing a date and time and a corresponding
>   format string. datetime

In order to see how to use the formats and when, you can see [strftime formats](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use dateutil's parse ?

```
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse('Saturday, 30 Nov, 2013')
datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 30, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime

st='Saturday, 30 Nov, 2013'
print datetime.strptime(st,'%A, %d %b, %Y')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2013-11-30 00:00:00
```

See [strptime()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm) at Tutorials point